# why is HTML interpreted while displaying it with syntax highlighter

Tags: php, html, syntaxhighlighter

I want to display some PHP in my HTML page using Alex Gorbatchev SyntaxHighlighter plugin.

My problem is that some code is interpreted by browser as I don't want to 
(just want to dispay it as plain text)

Code can be found there
http://codepen.io/hugsbrugs/pen/OPEyZZ

And the error I'm trying to get rid of is :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @spender, I ended doing :

```
<pre class="brush: php">
    <?php
    $code = file_get_contents('FILE_PATH');
    echo htmlentities($code);
    ?>
</pre>
```

I wish I could have used HEREDOC in PHP instead of storing my code in an external file but considering the use of single and double quotes, I couldn't achieve it ...

Comment: The javascript files you're trying to load, http://agorbatchev.typepad.com/pub/sh/3_0_83/scripts/shCore.js for example, don't exist. Use the correct URL's.

Comment: Your link exists ... don't know why you have an error (server error at the time you tested it ...)

Comment: Still a 404 for me..

Answer (score 1):

So you need to HTML encode the content so the browser does not interpret it as HTML.

http://php.net/htmlentities